# script tag returns 'not found' on newly written file

Tags: php, ajax, tags, file-not-found

I'm writing a webpage (in PHP / javascript) that is supposed to check whether jQuery.js exists at a certain location, write it to that location if it's not already there (by grabbing it from the internet), and then send the newly written jQuery to the client for use.  Right now I can't get this to happen on one load of the page.  I always have to refresh.

First, on the client side, I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script1.js"></script>
```

This script makes an AJAX call to the server, which checks for jQuery and writes it to disk if it's not there.  I make this an unusual *synchronous* AJAX call so the operation should finish before anything else happens.  Here's the relevant part of "script1.js". Since the call is synchronous, I don't have to check for when readyState is 4 and all that jazz.  The function should return only *after* the server reports back (right? Or is that wrong?).

```
var xmlhttp = getXmlhttp();  // gets an xmlhttp object appropriate to the browser.
xmlhttp.open("POST", "check_jQuery.php", false);  // 'false' for synchronous operation.
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send();
return;
```

Meanwhile on the server side ("check_jQuery.php") I've got:

```
if (!is_file("jQuery.js")) {
  file_put_contents("jQuery.js", file_get_contents($jQueryUrl));
}
while (!file_exists("jQuery.js")) sleep(1);
```

The while loop is a kludge to make sure that the function doesn't return until the file is well and truly written.  It does do that, but it doesn't seem to matter... Back on the client side, further down the page, I've got:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
```

But even if I put in an extra-long wait before returning from the server, the client-side script still fails to find jQuery.  If I reload the page however, it is found successfully.

So it seems like maybe the client is asking the server in advance whether the file exists, even though I'm trying to delay client-side execution until it *does* exist.  Interestingly, the 404 errors don't show up in the javascript debugger until after the server returns and well after the file has been successfully written.  Can someone explain why this is happening?  Is there a way to force the client to not ask for the file until after I've had a chance to write it?

Comment: why don't you deploy the application with all the artifacts in proper place without writing sophisticated download mechanism to include jquery

Comment: The application is going under version control, but 3rd-party libraries in active development like jQuery shouldn't be in the repository.  We could always just say "make sure you link to jQuery", but anyway I'm also interested in the answer to my question just because I want to understand how stuff is working.

Comment: The answer is simply, when the html is rendered browser will start connecting to other resources. so this happens quite fast and your jquery isn't finish downloading by that time.

Comment: Any ideas for a solution?